# Discord.py eval command: IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: discord.py

I want a **SIMPLE** eval command for my discord.py bot, all the code I have found does not work for me, the closest one I found was :

````
async def say(content):
await client.say(content)

@commands.command()
async def say(self, content):
await self.client.say(content)```

This just returns an error
````

Answer (score 1):

This error is one of the simplest errors in d.py. On the line

```
@commands.command()
async def say(self, content):
await self.client.say(content)
```

I assume this is where you are getting an error, and the most obvious error I can see at least,
You would need :

```
@commands.command()
async def say(self, content):
    await self.client.say(content)
```

And if you are running into issues like that without knowing how to fix them, I suggest you learn Python or refresh your memory, there is plenty of tutorials out there for discord.py as well as python, you can also read the discord.py docs [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). And maybe brush up on the rewrite branch of d.py, as to me it seems you are still writing in the old style.

Answer (score 0):

The error you describe in the title is pretty self-explanatory -- maybe you forgot to indent correctly somewhere. Anyway, as far as discord py is concerned, it appears as though you may be using outdated syntax. For comprehensive documentation (and some simple examples) please read the most recent documentation [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#sending-messages).